# IE doesn't display Spry Table properly

Tags: image, sorting, internet-explorer, spry

I've added a sortable spry table on my website. It works great everywhere except Internet Explorer. And I'm really struggling because no one can't tell me how to resolve the issue.
 In the page, you can see the table right at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

You're first defining the CSS `width` [like this](http://img819.imageshack.us/img819/2712/18949898.png), and then dynamically replacing it with the real values. However, this is invalid CSS which, apparently, IE not only ignores but discards altogether - the entire `style` attribute is removed from the DOM.

[image: The "style" attribute is missing altogether]

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the style for "results_bar" is right at the top of the page:
.results_bar {
background-image:url(../images/10.png); 
color:transparent; height:20px;
}
</style>
</head>"

For some reason this particular div didn't want to take the style from style.css that is why I had to put in in the <head>

So I don't quite get what should I do with my dynamic values in CSS width?